# Unexpected working of tail command implementation in Python

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to implement `tail` command using generators in Python. Here is the code.

```
import time

def tail(f):
    f.seek(0, 2)
    while True:
        line  = f.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        if not line.isspace():
            yield line


for l in tail(open('access.log')):
    print(l)
```

This code works perfectly as long as i don't change the `print()` function in the for loop. If change the print function in for loop to this:

```
for l in tail(open('access.log')):
    print(l, end="")
```

Suddenly it stops giving me updates. What is the problem ?

Comment: It's probably a buffering issue; what happens if you run the same code with `python -u`, or you add an explicit call to `sys.stdout.flush()` after the call to `print`?

Comment: Calling `sys.stdout.flush()` after print resolves the issue but i don't understand why. Can you please explain ?

Comment: `stdout` is line-buffered by default. So if you print stuff that doesn't end in a `\n` newline it patiently waits until it _does_ get a newline or a flush signal. You can call `sys.stdout.flush()`, but it's easier (and more efficient) to pass the optional `flush=True` keyword arg to the `print` function, eg `print(l, end="", flush=True)`

Comment: BTW, to do file tailing more efficiently, take a look at the [`selectors`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html#module-selectors) module.